# Issue with my mobile menu overflowing on mobile device

Tags: html, css, mobile, overflow, responsive

I'm currently learning about HTML and CSS, and a bit of JS.
I have created a mobile menu using a tutorial from youtube. I tried and check the website on my phone, the mobile menu, which is sent to the "right" of the screen when not active actually appears, and I can swipe towards it.

I have tried to use "overflow-x:hidden" on the body, the header, the nav, pretty much everything I could think of, it doesn't change anything. I've also tried to set the max-width of my body to 100vw, but it also doesn't stop the mobile menu from being on the right of my mobile screen when not active. Ideally, I'd like not to have any JS to solve this !

I hope I've been clear enough ! This is my first question on Stack Overflow so be gentle !

This is my code:

```js
const navSlide = () => {
  const burger = document.querySelector(".burger");
  const nav = document.querySelector(".main-menu");
  burger.addEventListener("click", () => {
    nav.classList.toggle("nav-active");  });
};

navSlide();
```

```css
.main-menu {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    right: 0px;
    height: calc(100vh - 8rem);
    top: 8rem;
    color: var(--font-bis);
    background-color: var(--font-color);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  }


.nav-active {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

```html
<header class="main-header">
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="main-nav">
            <div class="logo"><img src="img/logo.svg" alt="logo ubiquity" class="logo-img">
                <p>Ubiquity<span>Professionnal Web UI</span></p>
            </div>
            <ul class="main-menu">
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="" class="menu-link">Home</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="" class="menu-link">About</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="" class="menu-link">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="" class="menu-link">Blog</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="" class="menu-link">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="burger">
                <div class="line1"></div>
                <div class="line2"></div>
                <div class="line3"></div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

Cheers !

Comment: Add Your HTML & CSS & JS Code Here

Comment: Yeah add your code or share your website url so that we can look into your problem

Comment: @MohdSalman don't suggest to share a website. If website will be taken down at some point in future, the question will be useless.

Comment: Share your code so that we can help you.

Comment: Sorry, I just did, dunno if that's enough

Comment: Mobile device cannot hide right overflown elements. But hides left overflown elements. So use "transform: translateX(-100%);" instead of "100%". Then the nav menu will translates from left side.

Comment: @George thanks ! That works for me. I guess there has to be another way to do it if you absolutely want it to come from the right, but I'll make do for now ! Cheers

Comment: I will try now and let you know.